# How do I adjust this?

Tags: arduino-uno

We're supposed to create a Simon Says game for our final. My professor is telling me I shouldn't need to modify much with what I already have. but I'm so confused because it feels like starting over.
The way I have the Simon Says game now, it generates random numbers for each round but increments by one as the rounds increase. I need it to instead repeat the same sequence as the last and add a new random LED and so forth. Why is it so hard? What am I missing?
this is Arduino BTW

```
    int ledArray[10];
int buttonArray[10];
int loopCounter;
int ledCounter;
int inputCounter;
int game;
int waiting;
int pass;
int wait;
int timeUp;
int levelCounter[10];

//ALL THE BUTTONS & LEDS ARE GIVEN NAMES HERE SO THEY'RE EASIER TO REFERENCE
const int buttonRed = 6;
const int buttonYellow = 7;
const int buttonGreen = 9;
const int buttonBlue = 8;
const int r = 2;
const int y = 3;
const int b = 4;
const int g = 5;
const int x = 10;//LED ON PIN 10 IS THE WHITE LED USED FOR PROMPTS


///USED FOR PROCESSING AND COMPARING INPUTS
int randNumber;
int array_Cmp;

void youWin ()
{ digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(5, LOW);
  delay(100);
}

void ledPrompt()
//prompts player for inout during game after
//the LEDs have been picked randomly each round
{ digitalWrite(x, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(x, LOW);
  delay(50);
}

void gameHasStarted()
//LED prompt after first button
//is pushed to start the game
{
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(10, LOW);
  delay(100);
}

void fail() //LED sequence when the wrong input is entered
{ digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  delay(50);
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  delay(50);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  delay(50);
  digitalWrite(5, LOW);
  delay(50);
}

void waitToStart() //cycles through LEDs while waiting to start the game
{ digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  delay(250);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  delay(250);
  digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
  delay(250);
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  delay(250);
  digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
  delay(250);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  delay(250);
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
  delay(250);
  digitalWrite(5, LOW);
  delay(250);
}

int initiate()//FUNCTION WAITS FOR ANY OF 4 BUTTONS TO BE PUSHED TO START THE GAME
{ game = 0;
  waiting = 0;
  loopCounter = 1;
  randNumber = 0;
  ledCounter = 0;
  inputCounter = 0;
  pass = 2;
  //FUNCTION INCLUDES ALL OF THE ASSUMPTIONS NEEDED TO EXECUTE THE 1ST ROUND PROPERLY
  do {
    if (digitalRead(buttonRed) == LOW)
    { game = 2;
      gameHasStarted();
    }
    if (digitalRead(buttonGreen) == LOW)
    { game = 2;
      gameHasStarted();
    }
    if (digitalRead(buttonBlue) == LOW)
    { game = 2;
      gameHasStarted();
    }
    if (digitalRead(buttonYellow) == LOW)
    { game = 2;
      gameHasStarted();
    }
    else {
      waitToStart();
    }
  }
  while (game <= 1);
  delay(1000);
}//END OF GAME INITIATOR FUNCTION

int pickLed ()//FUNCTION WILL PICK A RANDOM LED
{
  do {
    randNumber = random(2, 6);
    digitalWrite(randNumber, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(randNumber, LOW);
    delay(100);
    if (randNumber == 2)
    { ledArray[loopCounter] = 0;
      ledCounter++;
    }
    if (randNumber == 3)
    { ledArray[loopCounter] = 1;
      ledCounter++;
    }
    if (randNumber == 4)
    { ledArray[loopCounter] = 2;
      ledCounter++;
    }
    if (randNumber == 5)
    { ledArray[loopCounter] = 3;
      ledCounter++;
    }
  }
  while (ledCounter < loopCounter);
  ledPrompt();//signals for input after it's done picking the LEDs for each round
  wait == 1;
}//END OF PICKLED FUNCTION

int waitForInput ()//FUNCTION WILL WAIT FOR USER INPUT OR END GAME AFTER 10 SECONS OF NO INPUT
{
  do
  {
    if (digitalRead(buttonRed) == LOW)
    { digitalWrite(r, HIGH);
      inputCounter++;
      delay(150);
      digitalWrite(r, LOW);
      delay(150);
      buttonArray[loopCounter] = 0;
    }
    if (digitalRead(buttonYellow) == LOW)
    { digitalWrite(y, HIGH);
      inputCounter++;
      delay(150);
      digitalWrite(y, LOW);
      delay(150);
      buttonArray[loopCounter] = 1;
    }
    if (digitalRead(buttonBlue) == LOW)
    { digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
      inputCounter++;
      delay(150);
      digitalWrite(b, LOW);
      delay(150);
      buttonArray[loopCounter] = 2;
    }
    if (digitalRead(buttonGreen) == LOW)
    { digitalWrite(g, HIGH);
      inputCounter++;
      delay(150);
      digitalWrite(g, LOW);
      delay(150);
      buttonArray[loopCounter] = 3;
    }
    else {
      wait++; //the wait counter is incremented each time the loop reads all 4 input and no input has been made
      delay(250);
    }//the delay here adds 1/4th of a second each time no input is made (every 4 loop here is 1 second);

    if (wait > 40) //40 divided by 0.25 = 10 seconds of wait
    {
      pass = 0;
      fail();
    } //after waiting 10 seconds for input the game automatically fails.
  }
  while (inputCounter < loopCounter);//WAIT FOR INPUT
}   //END OF WAIT_FOR_INPUT FUNCTION

int scoreInput ()//START OF SCORE_INPUT FUNCTION
{ if (memcmp(ledArray, buttonArray, sizeof(ledArray)) == 0)
  {
    delay(1000);
    loopCounter++;
    ledCounter = 0;
    inputCounter = 0;
    game++;
    pass = 2;
  }
  else
  {
    loopCounter = 0;
    ledCounter = 0;
    inputCounter = 0;
    pass = 0;
  }
}
//END OF SCORE_INPUT FUNCTION

void setup ()
{ randomSeed(analogRead(0));
  pinMode (r, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (y, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (b, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (g, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (buttonRed, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode (buttonYellow, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode (buttonGreen, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode (buttonBlue, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode (buttonRed, INPUT);
  pinMode (buttonYellow, INPUT);
  pinMode (buttonGreen, INPUT);
  pinMode (buttonBlue, INPUT);
  pinMode (x, OUTPUT);
  game = 0;
  waiting = 0;
  loopCounter = 1;
  randNumber = 0;
  ledCounter = 0;
  inputCounter = 0;
  pass = 2;
  timeUp = 2;
  initiate();
}


void loop ()//by using functions, the void loop section here is very short.
{
  do {
    pickLed();
    waitForInput();
    scoreInput();
    levelCounter++;
    if (loopCounter > 4)//states the game should end after round 10
    { youWin();
      pass = 0;
    }
  }
  while (pass > 1); // keeps the game going until round 10 or fail
  initiate();
}
```

Comment: sorry I could't post the code properly.

Comment: why would you generate numbers at the begining of each round?

Comment: It generates a random number for the 1st round and then the next round it generates 2 numbers and so forth. That's how I have it now. The problem is the numbers are different for each round which is wrong. My professor wants the numbers to be same as the last round but with a new random LED generated

Comment: that describes what the program does, which you already decribed in your post ... i did not ask for a description .... think about what i asked ... hint: why do you generate only one number before the first round?

Comment: Idk how to generate 10 randomly. I've tried the for loop but I don't know and it just sucks but I gave up

Comment: you have the right idea ... what does this mean? ... `I've tried the for loop but I don't know`  .... there are several lines in your code that should give you some ideas ... here is one of them ... `buttonArray[loopCounter] = 3;`

Comment: The thing is that the game works but it doesn't repeat the same sequence each round. It gives a nee random set with each round

Comment: i was wrong, you do not understand ... another hint: `it doesn't repeat the same sequence each round` ... then do not generate the sequence at each round